# Закрытие модального окна автоматически

Tags: php, javascript, html

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть сайт на bootstrap, на нём модальное окно с формой обратной связи, так вот нужно, что бы когда нажал Отправить скажем через 3 секунды закрыть модальное окно, можно даже отсчет, что бы пользователь понимал, а то шлют люди по 10 копий.

Php

```
$msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
$errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
// проверяем корректность полей
if($_POST['id_fio'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле <span style='color: #666;'>ФИО</span> не заполнено";
if($_POST['id_phone'] == "")    $errors[] = "Поле <span style='color: #666;'>Телефон</span> не заполнено";
if($_POST['id_type'] == "")    $errors[] = "Поле <span style='color: #666;'>Тип документа</span> не заполнено";
if($_POST['id_message'] == "") $errors[] = "Поле <span style='color: #666;'>Примичание</span> не заполнено";

// если форма без ошибок
if(empty($errors)){     
    // собираем данные из формы
    $message  = "ФИО: " . $_POST['id_fio'] . "<br/><br/>";
    $message .= "Email: " . $_POST['id_email'] . "<br/><br/>";
    $message .= "Телефон: " . $_POST['id_phone'] . "<br/><br/>";
    $message .= "Тип документа: " . $_POST['id_type'] . "<br/><br/>";
    $message .= "Примичание: " . $_POST['id_message'];      
    send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
    // выведем сообщение об успехе
    $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;font-size: 1.1em;'>Сообщение успешно отправлено! <br/> В ближайшее время я Вам отвечу!</span>";
}else{
    // если были ошибки, то выводим их
    $msg_box = "";
    foreach($errors as $one_error){
        $msg_box .= "<style>.messages{margin-bottom: 20px;}</style><span style='color: red;font-size: 1.2em;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
    }
}

// делаем ответ на клиентскую часть в формате JSON
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => $msg_box
));


// функция отправки письма
function send_mail($message){
    // почта, на которую придет письмо
    $mail_to = "******@yandex.ru"; 
    // тема письма
    $subject = "Заявка";

    // заголовок письма
    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
    $headers .= "From: Письмо с **** <support@***.ru>\r\n"; // от кого письмо

    // отправляем письмо 
    mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title centered" id="myModalLabel">Оформить заявку</h4>
                <p style="line-height: 1.2; margin-bottom: 0;">Мы с вами свяжемся</p>
            </div>

            <section id="message">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="contact-form">        
       <div class="controls">
         <div class="row">
             <div style="margin-left: 30px;">
                <input id="id_fio" type="text" class="input_form" placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество" required="" >
                <input id="id_email" type="email" class="input_form" placeholder="Email (не обязательно)" required="" >
                <input id="id_phone" type="tel" class="input_form" placeholder="Телефон 8 123 456 7890" required="" >
                <input id="id_type" type="text" class="input_form" required="" placeholder="">
                <textarea id="id_message" name="text_comment" maxlength="200" class="textarea_form" placeholder="Примечание, доп. информация"></textarea>
            </div>
             <div class="messages" style="margin-left: 30px;"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть <span id="timer"></span></button>
                <button type="submit" id="button_contacts" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>

            </div>
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button_contacts').click(function(){
            var form_name   = $('#id_fio').val();
            var form_email   = $('#id_email').val();
            var form_phone   = $('#id_phone').val();
            var form_type   = $('#id_type').val();
            var form_message = $('#id_message').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "post.php", 
                type: "post", 
                dataType: "json", 
                data: { 
                    "id_fio":   form_name,
                    "id_email":   form_email,
                    "id_phone":   form_phone,
                    "id_type":   form_type,
                    "id_message":   form_message
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('.messages').html(data.result); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Неплохо бы укоротить код, вместо if($_POST['id_fio'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле <span style='color: #666;'>ФИО</span> не заполнено";
писать if($_POST['id_fio'] == "")   $errors[] = "ФИО"; для каждой из 4-х строк, а в цикле, который ниже, добавлять эти вашы спаны)))

Answer (score 1):

Закрывайте модальное окно после нужного вам действия

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

или

```
$('#myModal').modal().hide();
```

для закрытия через определенное время используйте следующую функцию

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
}, 3000);
```

А вообще после клика на **кнопку отправить** я советовал бы вам банально ее **блочить**

```
$('#button_contacts').click(function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   $(this).html('Отправка...');
   ...
```

и менять надпись к примеру на "Отправка..."